# how can restrict access to media image URL in django

Tags: django, media-url

how can restrict access to media image url , and make it accessible only by access owner user in django ,

here is my class model :

```
class private_image(models.Model):
    i_user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='related_PRF_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_image= models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True )
```

and my media settings is :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media_url/'
```

for example : i don't want users put the image url like this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media_url/images/67155_0_AVemgEZ.jpg" in their browsers and open the image , if the request user not same owner user.

i believe,  i can make a small function to check access-user  and requested URL '/media_url/images/' to get image name , and then get an object from database using image name and
then check the owner(i_user) if same access-user .

but how can i tell Django to  use this function before service MEDIA_URL requests .

if you have an example , that will be very helpful .

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `requests` for **media** should go throught a specific view.

**myproject/urls.py**:

```
from myproject.views import media_access

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('media_url/images/<str:path>', media_access, name='media'),
    # or
    # url(r'^media_url/(?P<path>.*)', media_access, name='media'),
]
```

Add the view and check access.

**myproject/views.py**:

```
from django.http.response import FileResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def media_access(request, path):    
    access_granted = False

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if user.is_staff:
            # If admin, everything is granted
            access_granted = True
        else:
            # For simple user, only their documents can be accessed
            doc = user.related_PRF_user.i_image  #Customize this...

            path = f"images/{path}"
            if path == doc:
                access_granted = True

    if access_granted:
        response = FileResponse(user.related_PRF_user.i_image)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Not authorized to access this media.')
```

Plz tell me this works or not..

Comment: should i keep the media setting in settings.py file (MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media_url/') , or i have to remove it ?

Comment: @kder No no..Keep it bro..don't remove media url and root otherwise your media url will not work...

Comment: thank you it works , just i removed '/' from end of path in url, and before check "   if path == doc.name " i have added a new variable " path = f"images/{path}" " . kinldy update your answer if you like . thanks .